# simple tasks with grep, sed and the similar

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, disk-usage

The output of `du -sh folder` is some dimension and folder; how can I use `grep -o '*G'` and similar to just get the dimension, namely get rid of folder name?

Comment: Let's split those two separate questions into two [separate Questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: If your goal is to sum up the disk usage then you probably *don't* want to pass `-h` (human-readable) to `du`: you want the sizes to be listed in bytes for everything, to make it easier to combine the values.

Comment: @DanielPryden "*you want the sizes to be listed in bytes*" or -k or -m.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can offer a simple `cut` solution :

```
du -sh . | cut -f1
```

The standard delimiter in `cut` is tab, so no need for any additional options. Simply print field 1.

From your comment, it seems you are concerned with resources/speed so to quote Gilles from another answer:

> "Generally speaking, the more specialized a tool is, the faster it is.
>   So in most cases, you can expect `cut` and `grep` to be faster than `sed`,
>   and `sed` to be faster than `awk`."

Quoted from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132313/what-are-the-exact-differences-between-awk-and-cut-with-grep)

The ouput of `time` for both commands shows:

```
time du -sh /folder | awk '{print $1}'
60K

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.004s

time du -sh /folder | cut -f1
60k

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s
```

I believe you would need to repeat that multiple times, and take the average to make it a fair test, but either way, not much in it. Technically cut should be "faster".

Comment: +1 for recommending an oft-overlooked, and quite useful, command.

Answer (score 3):

You could use awk to only print the first column:

```
du -sh folder | awk '{print $1}'
```

For the file, also using awk:

```
awk '!($3="")' file
```

Comment: Thanks. Compared to grep, is it more resource draining? I plan to put this inside a script that is run every second to read my Dropbox folder size.

Comment: If you can find a way to do it with grep try to use `time` to compare the performance of both.

Comment: @jj_p If you are running this on a dropbox folder every second, the "resource drain"  is not going to be in the milliseconds differences in runtime between grep or awk or cut, it's going to be in running `du` on a remote filesystem.   that'd be like worrying about a single drop of rain when your entire town is flooded.

Comment: @cas well I'm running on local folder..

Comment: @jj_p even with a local folder, the disk I/O is going to consume far more resources than the negligible differences in CPU usage between the commands.  Network I/O for dropbox or any other remote fs just makes it worse.